# How to get the string of a qualifer in SXL

Tags: xslt

I have a qualifier that is generated dynamically, how can i get the string of a qualifier. Element.qualifier.qualifier, I want to obtain the string of the last qualifier.

Ps:

I know almost nothing about xslt, this is a project i inherited.

Thx

Comment: What language and/or library are you using? Please tag the question accordingly.

Comment: *Qualifier*?   It would help if you'd show sample XML so that you could reference a specific element or attribute in your question, especially if you're not familiar with XML terminology.  By the way, if you only need to select something from an XML document, XPath alone might suffice; XSLT goes beyond selection by supporting rearrangement of selected nodes.